# how to send SIGINT signal multiple times

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, signals, interrupt

I am trying to send a SIGINT signal to main thread from some other thread. The main thread has assigned a handler for for the signal. When I send first signal, it is caught in handler. But I want to send signal continuously. but after handling the first signal, the program terminates. I have put a while loop. So what I expect is that it should continue sending these signals. Following is my code

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

static void catch_function(int signo) {
    puts("Interactive attention signal caught.");
}

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    while(1)
    {
        Sleep(50);
        puts("Raising the interactive attention signal.");
        if (raise(SIGINT) != 0) 
        {
            fputs("Error raising the signal.\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
return 0;
}


int main(void) 
{
     if (signal(SIGINT, catch_function) == SIG_ERR) {
    fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    HANDLE thread;
    DWORD  threadId;
    thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &MyThreadFunction, NULL, 0, &threadId);
    if(!thread)
    {
        printf("CreateThread() failed");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        Sleep(50);
    }
    puts("Exiting.");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of following code is

```
Raising the interactive attention signal.
Interactive attention signal caught.
Raising the interactive attention signal.
```

I have tried using a simple example also. Here I am sending a signal 3 times, but only first time the signal is caught. After that the program terminated. Following is the code

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    printf("Received signal %d\n", signal);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Install a signal handler.
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    printf("Sending signal %d\n", SIGINT);
    raise(SIGINT);
    raise(SIGINT);
    raise(SIGINT);
    printf("Exit main()\n");
}
```

Output is

```
sending signal 2
Received signal 2
```

So I want to know how can I continue sending some signals from one thread  to some other thread? I want that one of my threads will send SIGINT signals and main will catch them and do some operations accordingly.

Comment: Why are you using the signal to *interrupt* as an "attention" signal? It's usually the signal sent when trying to cancel a program with CTRL-C. If you catch it, and have a problem leading a user to wanting to interrupt your program, it would no longer be possible using the usual standard way. You may want to use e.g. `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I want to do it for windows also. I think I cannot use SIGUSER1 and SIGUSR2 for that. Please let me know if I am incorrect.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461171/signal-handler-getting-called-in-wrong-thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically after the first signal, signal handler is reset to `SIG_DFL` (Unix V signals) and the default behaviour for `SIG_INT` to exit the program. This is what you observe. So it would require to reinstall the handler again. Install it again in the handler:

```
void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    printf("Received signal %d\n", signal);
}
```

A better approach would be to use [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead as it doesn't have this behaviour.

Comment: By using `sigaction` one can *control* the behavior with a flag.

Comment: Yes, not having to reinstall is an obvious advantage among other things.

Comment: @BlueMoon can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461171/signal-handler-getting-called-in-wrong-thread

Comment: but still sigaction(or any method) can not guarantee to entertain all signals generated